# Custom post type query with taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I use this query to call posts from a custom-type post I setup apart

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order'=> 'DES', 'post_type' => 'custom-post' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<div class="thumbnail">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
</div>
<?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h2>' ); ?>
<?php  echo '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>' ?>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Two questions:

1. Is that correct or can I improve it better somehow?
2. Is it possible to call posts that are placed **both** in 2 different taxonomy generated from that custom post type ("flowers" and "colors" for instance) and then call post that is in the "flowers" category but **not** in the "colors" one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question - yes, it is possible, you can use tax_query for this, for example, this query will get all posts that has any term of 'flowers' taxonomy AND 'colors' taxonomy:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // it is also possible to use OR
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'flowers',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'colors',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
) );
```

The second query will get all posts that have terms from 'flowers' taxonomy, but not from 'colors' taxonomy:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'flowers',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'colors',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS' // <-- Take a look at this operator
        )
    )
) );
```

The code is not tested

Here are also links to the Documentation, check out how to use WP_Query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#standard-loop

And also WP_Tax_Query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Testing your code I arrived finally to an answer:
In the first query I didn't use any 'operator' and it works!
In the second query I used the 'operator' 'IN' and 'NOT IN' and it worked!
Thank you